# Sitecore menu text has vanished

Tags: multilingual, settings

First of all, I followed this procedure.
[https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/101/~/link.aspx?_id=B685CC31771E466080080239FDBEA625&_z=z](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/101/%7E/link.aspx?_id=B685CC31771E466080080239FDBEA625&_z=z)

I downloaded the necessary files from the following link "Client translations" and imported them.
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/102/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_102.aspx

At the end of procedure, I changed Display Language.
Menu text has vanished.
[image: vanished menu]

[image: vanished setting]

At this time, we have also confirmed that the shell#lang of the cookie has been changed from en.

[image: Cookie]

Both menus and cookies were restored by adding "sc_lang=en" to the end of the URL.
However, the menu display language is still in English.
What do I need to do to translate successfully?

Comment: did you install the client translation package?

Comment: I don't know what a "client translation package" is.

Comment: you wrote: I downloaded the necessary files from the following link "Client translations" and imported them.  What steps you made here ? for me looks like you didn't installed this package: https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/~/media/BC59FD68B64A4428B746EC560CE5EF3E.ashx?date=20211101T103425

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was bad.
I installed and imported the file by Controll panel.